# Hide View by click on any part of the screen in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have a View which is the subView of the main view in iphone app I want that when subView is shown and user taps on part of the screen except the subView then subView should hide.

Here is the code which I got but it does not hide it :

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR;
tapGR = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)] autorelease];
tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.View addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];

// Add a delegate method to handle the tap and do something with it.

-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    // handling code
  [myViewSheet removeFromSuperView];

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol:
.h:

```
@interface YourView : UIView<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

.m:

```
@implementation YourView{
    UIView * subview;
}
```

...

```
    subview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
    [self addSubview:subview];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR;
    tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGR.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
```

...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
    if (touch.view == subView) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        return YES; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set userInteractionEnabled = YES on your main view (The one to which you are attaching the gesture recognizer.)